# Obtener localizacion y mostrarlo en mapa Google maps API

Tags: php, javascript, google-maps

Tengo un pequeño trozo de código que con la ayuda de la api de google maps muestra una ruta en dicho mapa desde un punto hasta otro. Tal y cómo muestro abajo

```html
<iframe width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0"
src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/directions?key=MI_API_KEY&origin=<?php echo $localizacion; ?>&destination=<?php echo $_POST['direccion']; ?>&avoid=tolls|highways" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

En el destino ($_POST['direccion'];) arroja los datos como la calle, numero, ciudad...

En el origen quiero que aparezca la geolocalizacion del dispositivo como coordenadas por ejemplo,
pero no consigo hacerlo

Answer (score 0):

En este link hay un ejemplo:  https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_geolocation.

Lo unico que hay que tener en cuenta es que `position.coords.latitude` nos da la latitud y `position.coords.longitude` nos da la longitud de forma automática.

Comment: Y como puedo meter las variables lat y long dentro del la ruta?

Answer (score 0):

Con el siguiente codigo puedes obtener la latitud y longitud:
URL: [Obtener coordenadas](https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_geolocation)

```
<button onclick="getLocation()">Try It</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var x = document.getElementById("demo");

function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    } else { 
        x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
    }
}

function showPosition(position) {
    x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
    "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;
}
</script>
```

donde `position.coords.latitude` es la latitud y `position.coords.longitude`
es la longitud, lo puedes agregar en tu URL de la siguiente manera:

```
src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/directions?key=MI_API_KEY&origin=<?php echo $localizacion; ?>&destination=<?php echo $_POST['direccion'] . '/@' . $latitud . ',' . $longitud; ?>&avoid=tolls|highways"
```

entre `$_POST['direccion]` y las coordenadas debe tener `/@` seguido de las coordenadas

Answer (score 0):

tengo un codigo que me permite obtener la ubicación real de usuario con presional un boton, tambien obtiene la latitud y logitud si lo necesita, tener en cuenta que deber cambiar la key de google maps

solo deber copia el codigo y pegalo en el servidor

```
<section class="col-lg-12 connectedSortable">
    <div class="box box-warning">
        <div class="box-header with-border">
            <h3 class="box-codigo">
                Lista de Arboles
            </h3>
            <button class="btn btn-block btn-primary" id="find_btn" type="button">
                Ubicar mi posición
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="box-body">
            <div class="">
                <div id="floating-panel">
                </div>
                <div id="map">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<style>
    #map {
       height: 100%;
    }
    html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
</style>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
    var map;
    function geocodeLatLng(geocoder, map, infowindow) {
        var input = document.getElementById('latlng').value;
        var latlngStr = input.split(',', 2);
    }


    var nuevosarboles = [0.0,0.0];
    function aaa() {
        alert("si paso");
        mgr.clearMarkers();
    }
    function deleteMarkers() {
        clearMarkers();
        markers = [];
    }
    function initMap(){
        var options = {
        zoom:16,
        center:{lat:4.302314898662877,lng:-74.80926649120488}
    }
     // New map
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), options);
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder;
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;


$("#find_btn").click(function (){
        if("geolocation" in navigator){
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){ 
                infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({map: map});
                var pos = {lat: position.coords.latitude, lng: position.coords.longitude};
                infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
                map.setZoom(19);
                infoWindow.setContent("Localización del usuario <br/>"+
                    "@can('Arboles Add')"+
                    "<a class='massmodal btn btn-success' href='#' id='massadd-modal' <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open'></span>Añadir un Árbol</a>"+
                    "@endcan"+
                    //"Lat : "+position.coords.latitude+" </br>Lang :"+ position.coords.longitude
                    "");
                //obtener el latitud y logitud 
                $('#latitud_mass').val(position.coords.latitude);
                $('#longitud_mass').val(position.coords.longitude);
                map.panTo(pos);
               // MostrarArbolesCercanos(position.coords.latitude,position.coords.longitude);
            });
        }else{
            console.log("Su navegador no soporta la Geo-localización ");
        }
});


}
</script>

<style>
    #map {
       height: 100%;
    }
    html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
</style>
<script async="" defer="" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&callback=initMap"></script>
```